# Sub Dropdown menu Disappearance

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I've been creating a navbar, and made some drop downs. For some reason, my submenu/sub or nested navbar doesn't seem to actually stay when I try to hover upon it. Is there something I should do to actually enable it? I've tried using jQuery (as shown below), using the + operator in CSS, creating a separate, hidden div to try to maintain the submenu's appearance, etc. Nothing really seems to work, and I'm slightly stumped. For the jQuery example below, it says submenu is not defined, but I don't really know how to fix it as I am not extremely frank with the error.

```css
body {
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    margin: 0;

  }

  .navbar {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #333;
  }
  
  .navbar a {
    float: left;
    font-size: 39px;

    float: left;
    display: block;
    color: #f2f2f2;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 17px;
  }
  .navbar a:hover {
    background-color: #ddd;
  }
  
  .navbar a.active {
    background-color: #04aa6d;
    color: white;
  }
  
  .dropdown {
    float: left;
    overflow: hidden;
  }
  
  .dropdown .dropbtn {
    font-size: 16px;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    color: white;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    background-color: inherit;
    font-family: inherit;
    margin: 0;
    /* transition: height 0.25s; */
  }
  
  .navbar a:hover,
  .dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
    background-color: red;
  }
  
  .dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
    min-width: 160px;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    z-index: 1;
  }
  
  .dropdown-content a {
    float: none;
    color: black;
    padding: 12px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
  }

  .dropdown-submenu {
    /* ---Check jQuery--- */
    display: none;
    z-index: 1;
    left:100%;
    top: 20px;
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
    min-width: 160px;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    position: absolute;
  }

  .dropdown-submenu a:hover {
    background-color: #ddd;
  }
  
  .dropdown-content a:hover {
    background-color: #ddd;
  }

  
  .dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
    display: block;
  }

  

  .collapse {
    position: absolute;
    background-color: rgb(80, 78, 78);
    color: #fffefed7;
    box-shadow: 0.3rem 0.3rem 5.5rem #525c5c, 0em 0em 0.9em #ffffff6b;
    cursor: pointer; 
    top: 4.5%;
    border-radius: 50%;
    border-color: rgba(32, 30, 30, 0.863);
    display: flex; /* or inline-flex */
    align-items: center; 
    justify-content: center;  
    width: 25px;
    height: 25px;
    right: 50%;
    transition: background-color 0.2s ease-out 1ms;
  }

  .collapse:hover {  
    background-color: rgb(192, 192, 192);
  }

  .collapse:active {  
    transform: translateY(1px);
    background-color: rgb(109, 103, 103);
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang = "en">
 <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel = "stylesheet" href = "cssjavascript/style.css"/>
    <script src="cssjavascript/addon.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Material+Symbols+Outlined:opsz,wght,FILL,GRAD@20..48,100..700,0..1,-50..200" />

    <style>
        h3 {
             left: 2%;
             max-width: 200px;
             padding: 20px;
             margin: 20px;
        }  
        

        p {
            max-width: 200px;
             padding: 20px;
             margin: 20px;
             word-wrap: break-word;  
        }

    </style>
    <title>Contact Page</title>
 </head>

 <body>
    <div class="navbar">
        <a href="#home">Home</a>
        <a href="#news">FAQ</a>
        <div class="dropdown">
   
          <button class="dropbtn">Coding &#9660;
            <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
          </button>
          <div class="dropdown-content">
            <a class = "parentdrop" href="#">Web Development &#9654;</a> 
          <div class = "dropdown-submenu">
            <a href="#">HTML</a>
            <a href="#">CSS</a>
            <a href="#">JavaScript</a>
          </div>
            <a href="#">Link 2</a>
            <a href="#">Link 3</a>
          </div>
        </div> 

        <a href="contact.html">Contact Us</a>

        <button title = "Collapse Navbar" class = "collapse"><span class="material-symbols-outlined">
            expand_less
            </span></button>
      </div>


      <h1 style = "position: relative; display: flexbox; text-align:center; width: auto;">Contact Page</h1>

    <form action="https://formsubmit.co/cryptoandcraze@gmail.com" method="POST" class = "formDiv">
        <input type="text" name="_subject" placeholder = "Write your subject here" required>
        <input type="email" name="email" placeholder = "Email Address" required>
        <!-- Change redirect value from local IP address to actual website link later -->
        <input type="hidden" name="_next" value="http://127.0.0.1:5500/thankyou.html">
        <input type = "text" name = "message" placeholder = "Write your message here..." required>
        <button type="submit">Send</button>
    </form>


    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
      let submenu =  document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-submenu");
      
        $(".parentdrop").on({

        mouseenter: function () {
          for (let i = 0; i < submenu.length; i++) submenu[i].style.display = "block";
        },

        mouseleave: function () {
          for (let i = 0; i < submenu.length; i++) submenu[i].style.display = "none";
        }
      });

   });

    $(".dropdown-submenu").on({

      mouseenter: function () {
        for (let i = 0; i < submenu.length; i++) submenu[i].style.display = "block";
      },

    mouseleave: function () {
        for (let i = 0; i < submenu.length; i++) submenu[i].style.display = "none";
      }
   });

    
      </script>
      
 </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
 $(document).ready(function(){
      let submenu =  document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-submenu");
      
        $(".parentdrop").on({

        mouseenter: function () {
          for (let i = 0; i < submenu.length; i++) submenu[i].style.display = "block";
        },

        mouseleave: function () {
          for (let i = 0; i < submenu.length; i++) submenu[i].style.display = "none";
        }
      });

  

    $(".dropdown-submenu").on({
      mouseenter: function () {
        for (let i = 0; i < submenu.length; i++) submenu[i].style.display = "block";
      },

    mouseleave: function () {
        for (let i = 0; i < submenu.length; i++) submenu[i].style.display = "none";
      }
   });
 });
```

```css
body {
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    margin: 0;

  }

  .navbar {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #333;
  }
  
  .navbar a {
    float: left;
    font-size: 39px;

    float: left;
    display: block;
    color: #f2f2f2;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 17px;
  }
  .navbar a:hover {
    background-color: #ddd;
  }
  
  .navbar a.active {
    background-color: #04aa6d;
    color: white;
  }
  
  .dropdown {
    float: left;
    overflow: hidden;
  }
  
  .dropdown .dropbtn {
    font-size: 16px;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    color: white;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    background-color: inherit;
    font-family: inherit;
    margin: 0;
    /* transition: height 0.25s; */
  }
  
  .navbar a:hover,
  .dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
    background-color: red;
  }
  
  .dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
    min-width: 160px;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    z-index: 1;
  }
  
  .dropdown-content a {
    float: none;
    color: black;
    padding: 12px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
  }

  .dropdown-submenu {
    /* ---Check jQuery--- */
    display: none;
    z-index: 1;
    left:100%;
    top: 20px;
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
    min-width: 160px;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    position: absolute;
  }

  .dropdown-submenu:hover {
    background-color: #ddd;
  }
  
  .dropdown-content a:hover {
    background-color: #ddd;
  }

  
  .dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
    display: block;
  }

  

  .collapse {
    position: absolute;
    background-color: rgb(80, 78, 78);
    color: #fffefed7;
    box-shadow: 0.3rem 0.3rem 5.5rem #525c5c, 0em 0em 0.9em #ffffff6b;
    cursor: pointer; 
    top: 4.5%;
    border-radius: 50%;
    border-color: rgba(32, 30, 30, 0.863);
    display: flex; /* or inline-flex */
    align-items: center; 
    justify-content: center;  
    width: 25px;
    height: 25px;
    right: 50%;
    transition: background-color 0.2s ease-out 1ms;
  }

  .collapse:hover {  
    background-color: rgb(192, 192, 192);
  }

  .collapse:active {  
    transform: translateY(1px);
    background-color: rgb(109, 103, 103);
  }
  
h3 {
     left: 2%;
     max-width: 200px;
     padding: 20px;
     margin: 20px;
}  


p {
    max-width: 200px;
     padding: 20px;
     margin: 20px;
     word-wrap: break-word;  
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang = "en">
 <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel = "stylesheet" href = "cssjavascript/style.css"/>
    <script src="cssjavascript/addon.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Material+Symbols+Outlined:opsz,wght,FILL,GRAD@20..48,100..700,0..1,-50..200" />
    <title>Contact Page</title>
 </head>
 <body>
    <div class="navbar">
        <a href="#home">Home</a>
        <a href="#news">FAQ</a>
        <div class="dropdown">
          <button class="dropbtn">Coding &#9660;
            <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
          </button>
          <div class="dropdown-content">
            <a class = "parentdrop" href="#">Web Development &#9654;</a> 
          <div class = "dropdown-submenu">
            <a href="#">HTML</a>
            <a href="#">CSS</a>
            <a href="#">JavaScript</a>
          </div>
            <a href="#">Link 2</a>
            <a href="#">Link 3</a>
          </div>
        </div> 

        <a href="contact.html">Contact Us</a>
        <button title = "Collapse Navbar" class = "collapse"><span class="material-symbols-outlined">
            expand_less
            </span></button>
      </div>


      <h1 style = "position: relative; display: flexbox; text-align:center; width: auto;">Contact Page</h1>

    <form action="https://formsubmit.co/cryptoandcraze@gmail.com" method="POST" class = "formDiv">
        <input type="text" name="_subject" placeholder = "Write your subject here" required>
        <input type="email" name="email" placeholder = "Email Address" required>
        <!-- Change redirect value from local IP address to actual website link later -->
        <input type="hidden" name="_next" value="http://127.0.0.1:5500/thankyou.html">
        <input type = "text" name = "message" placeholder = "Write your message here..." required>
        <button type="submit">Send</button>
    </form>

 </body>

</html>
```

Note: submenu variable used in document ready and you are uses in out of document that generate the issue. you can put mouseenter and leave code in document ready.